# Is it possible to select all columns but one column using SQL syntax?

Tags: mariadb

Consider these tables:

1. Brands (Id, Name, Logo, Ratings)
2. Products (Id, Title, Picture, Price)

Is it possible to use star selection to select **ALL but ID** fields from the `Brands` table in a join?

```
create view ProductViews
as
select
    p.*,
    -- Is it possible to use star selection to select all fields of the Brands, except the Id field?
    b.Name,
    b.Logo,
    b.Ratings
from Products p
inner join Brands b
on p.BrandId = b.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use star selection to select ALL but ID fields...

No, not without already explicitly listing all the columns you want in a view or CTE first, and then using `SELECT * FROM SuchViewOrCTE`.

You also shouldn't be using `SELECT *` *most* times because it is an anti-pattern that can affect performance and result in broken code as schema changes occur:

1. [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/5059085)
2. ["SELECT *" why is it an antipattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220216/select-why-is-it-an-antipattern)
3. [What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321299/5059085)